# Ember js button click is not working on Mac Dev

Tags: button, ember.js, click

I am working on an application where I am using Ember JS .the button click is not working on MAC devices(Pc or mobile ) but the same code is working on others.. Please help me with this

```
 {{#view App.AddNewFirm contentBinding="this"}}
  <div style="cursor:"pointer">
  <button style="cursor:pointer" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Add Firm</button>
  </div>
  {{/view}}
```

Comment: By *MAC* do you mean Apple?

Comment: Yupss... I tried this on i phone as well but not working on that too. On others like windows and Android its working.. the link is  http://test.mixorg.com/handsOn/app/

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same problem,
The click handler bound to the view did not fire on an ipad device.

We could fix it by binding click handler directly on the button, using the didInsertElement hook, instead of using the click handler ember provides

```
App.AddNewFirmView = Ember.View.extend({         
  didInsertElement:function(){  
    this.$('button').click(function(){
      console.log('click');
    });               
  },        
});
```

You could also wrap your view within a `<button> </button>` although i discourage this.

Comment: you should see this: http://swsharinginfo.blogspot.in/2013/03/solution-for-click-event-issue-on-ipad.html